# Unique intercepts approach for categorical variables in "rstanarm" package in R

Tags: rstanarm

**Background:**
McElearth (2016) in his [rethinking book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1482253445) pages 158-159, uses an index variable instead of dummy coding for a 3-category variable called "clade" to predict "kcal.per.g" (linear regression).

**Question:** I was wondering if we could apply the same approach in `"rstanarm"`? I have provided data and R code for a possible demonstration below.

```
library("rethinking") # A github package not on CRAN
data(milk)
d <- milk
d$clade_id <- coerce_index(d$clade) # Index variable maker
#[1] 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 # index variable

# Model Specification:
fit1 <- map(
alist(
kcal.per.g ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ) ,
mu <- a[clade_id] ,
a[clade_id] ~ dnorm( 0.6 , 10 ) ,
sigma ~ dunif( 0 , 10 )
 ) ,
data = d )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most analogous way to do this using the **rstanarm** package is with

```
library(rstanarm)
fit1 <- stan_glmer(kcal.per.g ~ 1 + (1 | clade_id), data = milk,
                   prior_intercept = normal(0.6, 1, autoscale = FALSE), 
                   prior_aux = exponential(rate = 1/5, autoscale = FALSE),
                   prior_covariance = decov(shape = 10, scale = 1))
```

However, this is not exactly the same for the following reasons:

1. Bounded uniform priors on `sigma` are not implemented because they are not a good idea, so I have used an exponential distribution with an expectation of 5 instead
2. Fixing the standard deviation on `a` is not implemented either so I have used a gamma distribution with an expectation of 10
3. Hierarchical models in **rstanarm** (and **lme4**) are parameterized with deviations from common parameters, so rather than using an expectation of 0.6 for `a`, I have used an expectation of 0.6 for the global intercept and the prior on `a` is normal with an expectation of zero. This means you need to call `coef(fit1)` rather than `ranef(fit1)` to see the "intercepts" as they are parameterized in the original model.